# Why can't you select top level elements in an HTML string with jQuery, and how do you get around it?

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML stored in a string which I parse using jQuery. The HTML is something like:

```
<div class='person'>
    <span class='name'>Joey</span>
    <img class='avatar' src='...'/>
</div>
<div class='person'>
    <span class='name'>Dee Dee</span>
    <img class='avatar' src='...'/>
</div>
<div class='person'>
    <span class='name'>Tommy</span>
    <img class='avatar' src='...'/>
</div>
<div class='person'>
    <span class='name'>Johnny</span>
    <img class='avatar' src='...'/>
</div>
```

So I use jQuery to parse the HTML like this (suppose the HTML is stored in the variable 'data'):

`$(".name", data)` returns all the .name elements

`$(".avatar", data)` returns all the .avatar elements

BUT `$(".person", data)` returns and empty object.

**So apparently jQuery cant parse the top level elements. Why is this? What is the best way to get around it?**

Of course I can always insert 'data' inside a dummy element and then parse it, but that doesn´t seem a very elegant solution to me...

Comment: You could wrap everything in another element, then it would work that way.

Comment: I know that Andy, but I dont like that solution because it looks very clumsy to me. So I would like to know how the jQuery experts deal with this, and maybe an explanation about why this happens...

Comment: it's because $('') looks for children in the current set. you could also use `$(data).filter('.person');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) -

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span').

and then from the '[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)' docs -

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

So the `$(".person", data)` selector will always return an empty result set (as it contains no `.person' descendants) unless you wrap it in a dummy object before searching.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! I didnt know that $('') was basically a shortcut to .find(). Thank you